# Can we see the multiplication of two functions in the nature?

Tags: waves, superposition

From the superposition principle, we can say that in nature, two waves superpose themselves to give a single wave with different (may be more or less than original two) amplitude.

This means addition of two functions (for example, $y=2\sin x$ and $y=2\cos x$) is possible. Similarly, can we see multiplication of two or more functions? If we can, what are the cases?

I have a feeling that resonance can be a result of multiplication of two functions. Can this be true?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you are looking for. My memory of high-school physics is that it mostly involved formulae of the for $A = BC$ and in most cases you can find something else that $B$ and $C$ depend on if you think about it a bit.

Comment: But multiplication is simply repeated addition. And resonance is result of the addition of a driving force, as least for simple harmonic motion based systems.

Comment: This post (v2) seems like a list question. See e.g. the [method of separation for PDEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Partial_differential_equations).

Comment: As you stated you can see the sum of 2 trigonometric functions. It also appears to be the product of two others, by means of trigonometric identities. A phenomenon you could observe to see the multiplication of two functions could be the beat phenomenon when tuning a guitar [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_(acoustics))

Comment: I'm guessing that's a high-school-level question, so answers and many comments are flying a bit too high. If that's correct, my very modest [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/374469/75633) might be more in tune...

Answer (score 3):

As you said, the superposition principle allows to add waves.
But superposition holds only for linear media, when the response $R$ of the medium to the driving force $F$ is linear with the force, e.g. $R=\alpha F$ with $\alpha$ a proportionality constant.

This is the case for *most* of optical/electromagnetic phenomena (with $R$ the polarization and $F$ the driving electric field), as well as in acoustic.
However, for sufficiently large driving forces, the response is generally not linear anymore so that the response takes a form $R=\alpha F+\beta F^2$.
The reason one needs large driving force is that usually $\beta<<\alpha$ and that also explains why we are rarely observing nonlinear effects in everyday life.

Now if F is the sum of two separate excitation $F=F_1+F_2$, the response will be

$R=\alpha F_1+\alpha F_2+\beta F_1^2+\beta F_2^2+2\beta F_1F_2$.

Here you are: the nonlinearity creates a response that is the multiplication of two functions. Note that the superposition principle is apparent only for the term of the 1st power of $F_{1,2}$, but that the cross term $2\beta F_1F_2$ invalidates the superposition principle for the overall result.

In the case of harmonic waves, the square term effectively creates a constant response as well as a component at twice the frequency. This can be see with the trigonometric relation $\cos^2(\omega t)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cos(2\omega t)$.

In optics, this property allows the generation of new colors. For example the usual green laser pointers are made of a first infrared laser at a wavelength of 1064nm that passes through a nonlinear crystal that double its frequency, hence dividing its wavelength by two, sot that the output is light at 532nm which is green.

On the other hand the cross term $F_1F_2$ will create frequencies that are the sum and the difference of the frequencies of two possible monochromatic waves interacting in a nonlinear medium. 
Finally, for even higher intensity, a third order term in the previous response becomes non-negligible, giving rise to another rich variety of phenomena.

A list of effects are described in the following wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_optics

Answer (score 1):

What crosses my mind is any physics where you have two distributions joint together. An example would be [Planck's distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law) of intensity of black-body radiation & [human eye sensitivity](http://www.npl.co.uk/publications/good-practice-online-modules/optical-radiation-safety/the-human-eye-and-light/the-eyes-response-to-colour/) (graph below). How we truly see the colors of the sun (their intensities) is given by multiplication of these two distributions.

[image: Sensitivity of human eye. Taken from npl.co.uk]

Another naive (I'm not the expert here) example would be conjoint use of multiple filters in a linear circuit/mechanical system. As each filter has a profile, the overall passed signal is multiplication of their profiles.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we see multiplication of two functions in nature?

Yes. One example is a pendulum: its oscillations can be described by a sine, and the decreasing amplitude (due to energy losses such as air drag) by an exponential. Therefore, the [damped pendulum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/62417/75633) movement [is given](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/255451/75633) by the product of both functions:

$$ \theta(t) = Ae^{- \gamma t} \cdot \sin (\omega \, t). $$

> resonance can be a result of multiplication of two functions

Not really. The ideal [resonant behavior](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/231603/75633) can indeed be modeled by the product of an oscillating function (such as the sine) and a growing exponential (the one above is a decreasing one). But you ask whether the resonance *results* from a multiplication, and I don't see how to frame the [usual picture](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/370533/75633) is this way.